# How to minimize or maximize windows from the Unity panel?

Tags: unity, windows, panel

In the Unity panel, when you left-click on an application that has multiple windows or instances open, it displays the Spread Mode, but when you left-click on a solitary application, it does absolutely nothing.

I'd like to be able to click on a solitary application and have it minimize or maximize, like in a traditional taskbar. Is there a way to accomplish that in Unity?

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess there is no updated ppa for 12.10 of minimize patch.It worked in 12.04 lts and even with older unity version then it is now in 12.04 by default..Maybe you should try to contact developer of patch and ask to update.Here is working ppa for 12.04. its Isaac Joseph's ppa and hes comments presented on page
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-get-dodge-windows-and-minimize.html